# Is this Javascript object literal key restriction strictly due to parsing?

Tags: javascript, object, parsing, object-literal

Please refer to the code below, when I "comment in" either of the commented out lines, it causes the error (in IE) of "':' expected".  So then is my conclusion correct, that this inability to provide a reference to an object value, as an object key in a string literal; is this strictly an interpreter/parsing issue?  Is this a candidate for an awful (or at least "bad") "part" of Javascript, in contrast to Crockford's "good parts"?

```
<script>
var keys = {'ONE': 'one'};

//causes error:
//var obj1 = {keys.ONE: 'value1'};
//var obj1 = {keys['ONE']: 'value1'};

//works
var obj1 = {};
obj1[keys.ONE] = 'value1';

//also works
var key_one = keys.ONE;
var obj2 = {key_one: 'value1'};
</script>
```

Comment: BTW `var key_one = keys.ONE; var obj2 = {key_one: 'value1'};` does not work as you expect it does. `obj2` s property will be `key_one` and not the the value of `key.ONE` thus not `one`.

Comment: Note that although the last example works, it creates an object with the property `key_one`, not the property `keys.One`. The variable `key_one` is irrelevant to the literal object in the next line.

Comment: got it....that could be confusing....it should either disallow all "unquoted" strings, or de-reference the references, whatever they may be

Comment: They are already disallowed in JSON specs. But javascript objects can have methods defined as `{somevar: 1, methodname:function(){ /*stuff*/ } }` and I suppose somebody didn't like putting his methodname in quotes ;)

Comment: @George: Alternatively they could have disallowed quoted names in object literals, like some other languages...

Comment: And if You don't use quotes the parser wont let You call Your method "..." which is possible with quotes `var obj={"...":function(){}}` and You can call it `obj["..."]();`. fun, huh? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The limitation of the literal object syntax is that the names has to be literal. As the names can be specified as an identifer as well as a string, it's not possible to use a variable instead.

This will create an object with a property `n`, not a property `answer`:

```
var n = 'answer';
var o = { n: 42 };
```

Comment: Numeric literals are valid property names as well. Also, in ES5, the names can be specified as an identifier name (i.e., not just identifiers, but also reserved words). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9568622/96656.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use variables as keys when defining object with `{}`

Therefore they are being interpreted as string names and can consist only of characters avaliable for variable names

the

`objectname[anythingThatReturnsValue]='value1';` is the way to go.

ALSO

You can generate a string and parse it

```
var s='{"'+keys.ONE+'": "value1"}';
var obj=JSON.parse(s);
//or
s='var obj2='+s;
eval(s);
```

Both above methods are bad practices for creating objects in JavaScript and I don't recommend them.

Comment: You CAN use variables as keys when defining objects with {}, see the second "also works" block.

Comment: @George: No, you can't. The code runs, but it does not use the variable in the literal object.

Comment: @George: He means its a `syntax error` and there isn't anything you can do about it :)

Comment: @George - to be clear: `var obj2 = {key_one: 'value1'};` is the same as `var obj2 = {"key_one": 'value1'};` - key_one will be the name of the field.

Comment: @George: Clarifying Guffa's reply: The `key_one` in in the second "also works" example *is* the name of the key; if you examine the object, it will have a property called "key_one", *not* "one" as it would if the *value* of `key_one` were being used when you created the literal.

Comment: @naugtur: For JSON, I think you may have to also quote the key `var s = '{" + keys.ONE + '":"value1"}';`

Comment: Didn't mean to bring up an old answer, just saw this passing by :)

Answer (score 2):

Think about it: if it were to work the way you want it would totally introduce a language ambiguity.

```
var obj = {something:"red"}
var obj = {"something":"red"}
```

The two statements are equivalent in JavaScript, because bareword keys are "autoquoted." So if `something` means the literal string "something", how it could also refer to the variable "something". It can't. So if you want to use variables they have to go in square bracket notation instead of `key : value` notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var obj = {};
var val = 'foo';

obj[val] = 'bar'; 

obj.foo >>> 'bar';
```