# Passing array name as parameters in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and I'm doing an update of my db by using findByIdAndUpdate() function. I'd like to push elements into different arrays present in my document. I have in my document different array with different names. May I pass as parameter the name array to this function or I should create different function where every function has a different `nameArray`?

```
  this.findByIdAndUpdate(User._id,
                        {$push:{nameArray: 'element'}}, 
                        {upsert: true},
                        callback);
```

Comment: JavaScript Object literals don't currently allow variables as keys. An identifier on left of the `:` will be taken for its name, so `"nameArray"` is the name of the property. Related: [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050) and related to [Is this Javascript object literal key restriction strictly due to parsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873163)

Comment: Though, for future reference, current ECMAScript 6 drafts have defined a *ComputedPropertyName* syntax for Object initializers -- `{ [nameArray]: 'element' }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Node.js 4.x** you can use the [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6) syntax to do this directly in the `$push` object literal:

```
this.findByIdAndUpdate(User._id,
                       {$push: {[nameArray]: 'element'}}, 
                       {upsert: true},
                       callback);
```

In previous versions, you need to build your `$push` object programmatically:

```
var push = {};
push[nameArray] = 'element';
this.findByIdAndUpdate(User._id,
                       {$push: push}, 
                       {upsert: true},
                       callback);
```