# Can I add a key-value pair to an object and have the key be equal to a variable?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I want to add a key-value pair to an object, but i want the key to be equal to a variable. Here's what I mean:

```
var variable;

Object.assign(myObject, {variable: value})
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this Javascript object literal key restriction strictly due to parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873163/is-this-javascript-object-literal-key-restriction-strictly-due-to-parsing)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty not relevant after ES6 introduced computed property names `{[computed]: somveValue}`

Comment: @VLAZ most certainly relevant.  That question can still accept answers that reflect ES6.  It happens all the time here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Following code to use a variable as a key. Use `[]` operator to set the variable value to the key.

```
const key = "variableKey";

const object = {};

Object.assign(object, {[key]: 'value'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `Object.assign()`, you can just add the key directly to your object:

```
var variable = "value";

myObject[variable] = variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN documentation:

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string.
>
> Please note that all keys in the square bracket notation are converted to string unless they're Symbols, since JavaScript object property names (keys) can only be strings or Symbols

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Try your self into your browser console, the key will be named as `"[object Object]"`, the same result of calling `obj.toString()`:

```
let obj = {}
obj[new Object] = 'val'
console.log(obj)
```